# Method that returns any type in Java

Tags: java, return-type

I'm in a grade 11 computer science course and I'm trying to code a file that simplifies a lot of code. Right now I'm trying to merge input and output into one method;

```
public static void askln(String text, String type){
     System.out.println(text);
     if(type.equals("int"))
          return getInt();
     if(type.equals("char"))
          return getChar();
     if(type.equals("String")) 
          return getString();
     if(type.equals("double"))
         return getDouble();
     if(type.equals("float"))
         return getFloat();
     if(type.equals("long")) 
         return getLong();
}
```

`getInt()` is a method that gets an integer from the user. I'm assuming people will understand what the other getters do.

**This code doesn't work because 'void' won't return anything.** I was wondering if there was a return type that would allow me to return any value.

Comment: `public static Object`?

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Don't compare strings like this. In general, use `equals`; but in this case, use a switch.

Comment: I think you might do this with generics. Java is much stronger typed than other languages because having an unknown return type leads to bugs. Such a thing is frowned upon.

Comment: yeah perhaps make it a class or a struct with all these types and then return struct_name.value or class_object.value as it is hetrogenous (combination of types) hence we use object or struct_name as class identifiers to fetch concrete types

Comment: I don't know the context of the code you're writing, but in general such kludges are not necessary and should prompt you to take another look at what your code is doing.

Answer (score 6):

You should swap the parameter `String type` to `Class<T> type` and your return type to `T`. You have to define a generic parameter right before the return value, so the signature will be as follows: `public static <T> T askln(String text, Class<T> type)`.

To make your compiler happy, you probably should have the `getXXX()` methods return Object and casting it while returning to `T`.

Comment: Could that used with a primitive type (say `float`), or only with an object (say `Float`)?

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to have a function as a parameter to the method. This solution is based on this since the value you get from the user as input can be handle as a string and then we need a function that converts a string to the desired type.

```
public static <R> R askln(String text, Function<String, R> function){
    System.out.print(text);
    String str = getValue();
    return function.apply(str);
}
```

An example for a double

```
Function<String, Double> f = (Double::parseDouble);
Double d = askln("Type a number ", f);
```

and an integer

```
Function<String, Integer> f2 = (Integer::parseInt);
Integer i = askln("Type an integer", f2);
```

You can then have different functions defined for converting to each supported type.